# Read .txt file with PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

using php, I have to read a txt file (UTF-8 format) in which there are values to be inserted into a mysql db, based on character length.

This is my script:

```
if (($handle = fopen(DIRECTORY_FILE.'test.txt', "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while ($data = fgets($handle)) {                 
       $mod = (int)substr($data, 0,7);
       $cod = (int)substr($data, 10,3);
       $descr = trim(substr($data,13,255));
       $descr2 = trim(substr($data,268,255));
       $seq = (int)substr($data, 523,4);
       $codord = (int)substr($data, 527,20);           
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

This works well until there are no special characters.

I noticed that when there is a degree symbol **" ° "**, is counted as 2 length, causing an error in the reading of the txt.

How can I ensure that the count is correct?

Thanks

Comment: [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: Oh...many thanks :)